# MongoDB Java Simple Example fails

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongo DB server is running on local machine. I can open mongo shell and query the database without any issue.

The java file compiles without any errors. However while executing I get error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient
        at mongoTest.main(mongoTest.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Sample Java code which I wrote is shown below. When I execute the file at command prompt

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;

import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.mongodb.Block;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import com.mongodb.client.result.DeleteResult;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.*;
import com.mongodb.client.result.UpdateResult;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class mongoTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClient c = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = c.getDatabase("video");
        MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection("movieDetails");

        System.out.println(collection.count());

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a problems with your classpath. How are you executing the program? Through an IDE or via the command-line?

Comment: Compiled the java file at command line. No errors during compilaton. Tried to execute the same using command java mongoTest

Comment: And, when you compiled your class, did you you specify a classpath option pointing to your MongoDB JARs?

Comment: Yes...  FYI MongoDB Server version is 3.6.2  and Java 8 update 171

Compile statement at command line is - 

javac -cp .;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\mongo\bson-3.6.2.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\mongo\mongodb-driver-3.6.2.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\mongo\mongodb-driver-core-3.6.2.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\mongo\mongo-java-driver-3.6.2.jar mongoTest.java

No errors during compilation

Answer (score 2):

You'd just need to run the class with something like:

`java -cp <path-to-your-mongodb-jars> mongoTest`

It's also standard Java practice to capitalise the name of your class, so `MongoTest` rather than `mongoTest`

Comment: Thank you.. that worked...  Also regarding the java practices.. I will keep it in mind. Just started programming in java and mongo

Comment: If you haven't come across it already, check out the free online MongoDB course for Java developers at https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101J/about. It's well worthwhile.

Comment: That was the first thing that I saw :) . I will be definitely doing that course when the next run starts on 29th of this month. Thank you